# Select com Campo Nulo

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, nullable

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa em um banco de dados de alunos, e comecei a ter o seguinte problema: Todas as vezes que um aluno deixou de preencher o campo "endereço", apesar de ele ter todos os outros dados na tabela, o select não retorna esse aluno de jeito nenhum.

TABELA PESSOA

| id_pessoa | cpf | identidade | id_endereço |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 236589 | 04245897123 | 036690000 | 234567 |
| 236753 | 04245897123 | 036690000 | NULL |
| 224569 | 04245897123 | 036690000 | NULL |

TABELA ENDEREÇO

| id_endereco | complemento | bairro | cidade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 234567 | Rua X Casa y | Casa Nova | RIO |
| 256713 | RUA Fulano casa 23 | MOrada X | SÂO PAULO |
| 223269 | Rua ciclano nº 22 | HOrtolandia | CURITIBA |

SEGUE A QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pessoa.nome as NOME, pessoa.cpf_cnpj as CPF, dis.matricula as MATRICULA, pessoa.numero_identidade as IDENTIDADE, 
pessoa.email as EMAIL, pessoa.data_nascimento as IDADE, pessoa.sexo as SEXO,
ende.logradouro as ENDERECO, ende.complemento as COMPLEMENTO, ende.bairro as BAIRRO
FROM comum.unidade un
INNER JOIN "public".curso cs ON cs.id_unidade = un.id_unidade
INNER JOIN "public".discente dis ON dis.id_curso = cs.id_curso
INNER JOIN comum.pessoa pessoa ON pessoa.id_pessoa = dis.id_pessoa
INNER JOIN ensino.matricula_componente mat ON mat.id_discente = dis.id_discente
INNER JOIN ensino.turma turma ON turma.id_turma = mat.id_turma
INNER JOIN comum.endereco ende ON pessoa.id_endereco = ende.id_endereco
WHERE cs.nivel IN ('G','L','E','S','D') -- níveis de curso: G [GRADUAÇÃO], L [LATO SENSU], S [STRICTO SENSU], E [MESTRADO], D [DOUTORADO], R [RESIDÊNCIA], F [FORMAÇÃO COMPLEMENTAR] 
AND turma.ano = 2020 -- mudar ano
AND cs.id_modalidade_educacao IN (1,2) -- modalidades de educação: 1 [PRESENCIAL], 2 [A DISTÂNCIA], 3 [SEMI-PRESENCIAL]
```

Resumindo, queria fazer esta busca e retornar os dados das pessoas que tem todos os outros dados mesmo que não tenha endereço, mesmo ele sendo uma chave dentro da pesquisa. Pois existem pessoas que tem todos os dados da pesquisa, e as que não tem o endereço não estão retornando.

OU SEJA, queria o retorno de todos independente de ter ou não endereço cadastrado, já que elas tem todos os outros dados.
Quando faço a pesquisa sem o campo endereço, todos os candidatos são retornados normalmente.

Comment: Você esta usando INNER JOIN.
Logo ele só vai retornar resultados quando o valor coincidir nos dois lados da relação.
Você pode usar um LEFT JOIN, muito bem explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join), para solucionar seu problema.

Comment: obg, mano, realmente resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Substitua o "inner join" por "left join" ou outro join da sua preferencia.

Ex:

```
left JOIN "public".curso cs ON cs.id_unidade = un.id_unidade
left JOIN "public".discente dis ON dis.id_curso = cs.id_curso
left JOIN comum.pessoa pessoa ON pessoa.id_pessoa = dis.id_pessoa
left JOIN ensino.matricula_componente mat ON mat.id_discente = dis.id_discente
left JOIN ensino.turma turma ON turma.id_turma = mat.id_turma
left JOIN comum.endereco ende ON pessoa.id_endereco = ende.id_endereco
```

Assim ele irá retornar o resultado da row mesmo que os campos da ligação join seja nulo.

Comment: A única tabela que estava dando erro era a de endereço, e realmente o left join, conseguiu resolver o problema. obg pela ajuda.